# How to resolve JMeter ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: null?

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using JMeter in NON-GUI mode to execute tests from a Docker container. My test uses Selenium web driver with Chrome. I'm having an error that shows in `jmeter.log` but I don't know how to resolve it.

The error is:

> ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: null

When I run the test locally in my computer the test executes correctly, but in Docker using JMeter non-gui mode it doesn't work.

Test configuration in local JMeter:

[image: Test a configuration in local]

Execution in Docker:

[image: Execution in non-gui mode]

Log fragment with error

[image: Log fragment with error]

### Edit

Dockerfile

```
FROM  anapsix/alpine-java:8_jdk
LABEL maintainer="origds@gmail.com"
STOPSIGNAL SIGKILL
ENV JMETER_VERSION 5.1.1
ENV JMETER_HOME /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}
ENV JMETER_BIN ${JMETER_HOME}/bin
ENV PATH ${JMETER_BIN}:$PATH
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh \
 && apk add --no-cache \
    curl \
    net-tools \
    shadow \
    su-exec \
    tcpdump  \
 && cd /tmp/ \
 && curl --location --silent --show-error --output apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz \
 && curl --location --silent --show-error --output apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz.sha512 https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz.sha512 \
 && sha512sum -c apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz.sha512 \
 && mkdir -p /opt/ \
 && tar x -z -f apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt \
 && rm -R -f apache* \
 && sed -i '/RUN_IN_DOCKER/s/^# //g' ${JMETER_BIN}/jmeter \
 && sed -i '/PrintGCDetails/s/^# /: "${/g' ${JMETER_BIN}/jmeter \
 && sed -i '/PrintGCDetails/s/$/}"/g' ${JMETER_BIN}/jmeter \
 && chmod +x ${JMETER_HOME}/bin/*.sh \
 && jmeter --version \
 && rm -fr /tmp/*
WORKDIR /jmeter
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["jmeter", "--?"]

## JMETER plugins
ENV JMETER_PLUGINS_MANAGER_VERSION 1.3
ENV CMDRUNNER_VERSION 2.2
ENV JSON_LIB_VERSION 2.4
ENV JSON_LIB_FULL_VERSION ${JSON_LIB_VERSION}-jdk15
ENV NUMBER_OF_FILES_UNDER_LIB 144
ENV NUMBER_OF_FILES_UNDER_LIB_EXT 74
RUN cd /tmp/ \
 && curl --location --silent --show-error --output ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager-${JMETER_PLUGINS_MANAGER_VERSION}.jar http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-manager/${JMETER_PLUGINS_MANAGER_VERSION}/jmeter-plugins-manager-${JMETER_PLUGINS_MANAGER_VERSION}.jar \
 && curl --location --silent --show-error --output ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/cmdrunner-${CMDRUNNER_VERSION}.jar http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=kg/apc/cmdrunner/${CMDRUNNER_VERSION}/cmdrunner-${CMDRUNNER_VERSION}.jar \
 && curl --location --silent --show-error --output ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/json-lib-${JSON_LIB_FULL_VERSION}.jar https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/${JSON_LIB_VERSION}/json-lib-${JSON_LIB_FULL_VERSION}.jar \
 && java -cp ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager-${JMETER_PLUGINS_MANAGER_VERSION}.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller \
 && PluginsManagerCMD.sh install \
blazemeter-debugger=0.6,\
bzm-hls=1.2,\
bzm-http2=1.4,\
bzm-parallel=0.9,\
bzm-random-csv=0.6,\
bzm-rte=1.0.4,\
bzm-siebel=0.1.0-beta,\
custom-soap=1.3.3,\
jmeter.backendlistener.elasticsearch=2.6.0,\
jpgc-autostop=0.1,\
jpgc-casutg=2.8,\
jpgc-cmd=2.2,\
jpgc-csl=0.1,\
jpgc-csvars=0.1,\
jpgc-dbmon=0.1,\
jpgc-directory-listing=0.2,\
jpgc-dummy=0.2,\
jpgc-ffw=2.0,\
jpgc-fifo=0.2,\
jpgc-filterresults=2.2,\
jpgc-functions=2.1,\
jpgc-ggl=2.0,\
jpgc-graphs-additional=2.0,\
jpgc-graphs-basic=2.0,\
jpgc-graphs-composite=2.0,\
jpgc-graphs-dist=2.0,\
jpgc-graphs-vs=2.0,\
jpgc-hadoop=2.0,\
jpgc-httpraw=0.1,\
jpgc-jms=0.2,\
jpgc-jmxmon=0.2,\
jpgc-json=2.7,\
jpgc-lockfile=0.1,\
jpgc-mergeresults=2.1,\
# jpgc-oauth=0.1,\
jpgc-pde=0.1,\
jpgc-perfmon=2.1,\
jpgc-plancheck=2.4,\
# jpgc-plugins-manager=${JMETER_PLUGINS_MANAGER_VERSION},\
jpgc-prmctl=0.4,\
jpgc-redis=0.3,\
jpgc-rotating-listener=0.2,\
jpgc-sense=3.5,\
jpgc-standard=2.0,\
jpgc-sts=2.4,\
jpgc-synthesis=2.2,\
jpgc-tst=2.5,\
jpgc-udp=0.4,\
jpgc-webdriver=3.0,\
jpgc-wsc=0.7,\
jpgc-xml=0.1,\
jpgc-xmpp=1.5.1,\
kafkameter=0.2.0,\
mqtt-sampler=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,\
netflix-cassandra=0.2-SNAPSHOT,\
ssh-sampler=1.1.1-SNAPSHOT,\
tilln-sshmon=1.1,\
tilln-wssecurity=1.6,\
websocket-sampler=1.0.2-SNAPSHOT,\
websocket-samplers=1.2.1 \
 && jmeter --version \
 && PluginsManagerCMD.sh status \
 && chmod +x ${JMETER_HOME}/bin/*.sh \
 && if [ `ls -l /opt/apache-jmeter-*/lib/ | wc -l` != ${NUMBER_OF_FILES_UNDER_LIB} ]; then exit -1; fi \
 && if [ `ls -l /opt/apache-jmeter-*/lib/ext/ | wc -l` != ${NUMBER_OF_FILES_UNDER_LIB_EXT} ]; then exit -1; fi \
 && rm -fr /tmp/*

# Install Gecko Driver
RUN curl -sL "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz" | \
    tar -xz -C ${JMETER_HOME}/bin

#Install Chromium and ChromeDriver
RUN \
  echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
  && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
  && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
  && apk --no-cache  update \
  && apk --no-cache  upgrade \
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gifsicle pngquant optipng libjpeg-turbo-utils udev ttf-opensans chromium \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* /tmp/* /usr/include
RUN apk add chromium-chromedriver
RUN cp /usr/bin/chromedriver ${JMETER_HOME}/bin
COPY ./workaround.sh /tmp/workaround.sh
RUN chmod +x /tmp/workaround.sh
RUN cp /tmp/workaround.sh ${JMETER_HOME}/bin

# Install vnc, xvfb in order to create a 'fake' display and firefox
RUN sed -i -e 's/v[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]/edge/g' /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add x11vnc
RUN apk add xvfb
RUN apk add firefox --update-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ --allow-untrusted
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
RUN     mkdir ~/.vnc
# Setup a password
RUN x11vnc -storepasswd 1234 ~/.vnc/passwd

# Install new guava version
RUN wget "http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/guava/guava/23.0/guava-23.0.jar" -O "guava-23.0.jar"
RUN su 
RUN mv ./guava-23.0.jar ${JMETER_HOME}/lib
RUN rm ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/guava-19.0.0.jar
RUN exit
```

jmeter.log

```
2019-06-29 11:55:40,517 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_EN
2019-06-29 11:55:40,565 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: /opt/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/user.properties
2019-06-29 11:55:40,565 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: /opt/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/system.properties
2019-06-29 11:55:40,576 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2019 The Apache Software Foundation
2019-06-29 11:55:40,576 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 5.1.1 r1855137
2019-06-29 11:55:40,576 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_202
2019-06-29 11:55:40,576 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
2019-06-29 11:55:40,576 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Linux
2019-06-29 11:55:40,576 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=amd64
2019-06-29 11:55:40,576 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=4.9.125-linuxkit
2019-06-29 11:55:40,576 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8
2019-06-29 11:55:40,576 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.awt.headless=true
2019-06-29 11:55:40,576 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =1073741824
2019-06-29 11:55:40,577 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =2
2019-06-29 11:55:40,585 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (EN)
2019-06-29 11:55:40,585 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (EN)
2019-06-29 11:55:40,585 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=/opt/apache-jmeter-5.1.1
2019-06-29 11:55:40,585 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =/jmeter
2019-06-29 11:55:40,586 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =/jmeter
2019-06-29 11:55:40,586 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: IP: 172.17.0.2 Name: e31d62320a47 FullName: e31d62320a47
2019-06-29 11:55:40,596 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='/jmeter'
2019-06-29 11:55:40,612 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/workspace'
2019-06-29 11:55:40,917 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2019-06-29 11:55:40,947 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2019-06-29 11:55:40,957 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2019-06-29 11:55:40,973 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: /workspace/login_test_chrome.jmx
2019-06-29 11:55:41,058 INFO o.a.j.p.h.c.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_
2019-06-29 11:55:41,087 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2019-06-29 11:55:41,087 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2019-06-29 11:55:41,088 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2019-06-29 11:55:41,088 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2019-06-29 11:55:41,153 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Creating summariser <summary>
2019-06-29 11:55:41,171 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2019-06-29 11:55:41,172 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-06-29 11:55:41,172 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-06-29 11:55:41,190 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2019-06-29 11:55:41,190 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2019-06-29 11:55:41,504 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Running test (1561809341503)
2019-06-29 11:55:41,543 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2019-06-29 11:55:41,543 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2019-06-29 11:55:41,543 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2019-06-29 11:55:41,544 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2019-06-29 11:55:41,567 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2019-06-29 11:55:41,567 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2019-06-29 11:55:41,573 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2019-06-29 11:55:43,052 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: null
2019-06-29 11:55:43,100 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2019-06-29 11:55:43,100 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2019-06-29 11:55:43,184 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-06-29 11:55:43,186 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary =      1 in 00:00:02 =    0.6/s Avg:     0 Min:     0 Max:     0 Err:     1 (100.00%)
```

I'm using these versions:

- ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.103
- Chromium 73.0.3683.103

Test Code:

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium); //WebDriver classes
var support_ui = 
JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait); 
//WebDriver classes
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000);

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart(); //captures sampler's start time
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();
WDS.log.info("Sample started");

WDS.browser.get('http://192.168.1.68:80/login/index.php'); //opens 
website specified in 'localhost' docker 
WDS.log.info("Navegación hasta login Aula Virtual UV");

var usernameField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('username'));  
//username
usernameField.click(); //click s search field
usernameField.sendKeys(['user']);
WDS.log.info("username 'user' wrote");

var passwordField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('password')); 
//password
passwordField.click(); //Click Search Button
passwordField.sendKeys(['bitnami']);
WDS.log.info("password wrote");

var loginButton = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('loginbtn')); 
//login button
loginButton.click(); //Click Login Button
WDS.log.info("Clicked on the login button");

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd
WDS.quit();
```

Comment: Copied from an answer below (as it is not really answer material). To get assistance on questions of this kind, readers would need  1. [jmeter.log](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) file from the Docker container 2. Your [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) 3. [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/) details

Comment: I added this information after the EDIT tag in question

Comment: Thank you. These were conditions given by an answerer below, and I agree you have met them, but they now seem to be declining to help further. However, your time has not been wasted - the question probably needed them anyway. Are you still seeking assistance on this question?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()` instead of `WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd`? also can you add the text and not image of script?

Comment: @origds: to make best use of the bounty, try to answer any questions as they come in - it will only last for another five days. There's a question above that needs an answer - other readers may not offer their own thoughts until that issue is resolved. Indeed, perhaps that is the answer?

Comment: @user7294900 Still is throwing the error no matter if I use ```WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()``` or ```WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd```. Thank you @halfer.

Comment: From @user7294900: _also can you add the text and not image of script?_ (There is only value in adding a picture of the editor if there is something there other than text that the user needs to see).

Comment: Unfortunately, the bounty is likely to expire on this question. It is possible that the lack of timely updates meant that the 200+ people who saw it decided that it was not possible or ready to answer. If you get a bounty again, or if you add one yourself, try to be particularly active in supplying information and updates over the bounty period, in order to make best use of it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I just added the test code.

Comment: can you show entrypoint.sh file?